# NSOpenPanel under Sandbox - Access Sockets in User Selected folder

Tags: mysql, macos, sockets, appstore-sandbox, nsopenpanel

In a sandboxed app, an NSOpenPanel doesn't display sockets, e.g. /tmp/mysqld.sock

[image]

[image]

The sockets do appear if you use

```
[urlArr setArray:[fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:selectedFilePath error:&err]];
```

`urlArr` contains the socket. But it hasn't been selected by the user, so you can't create a bookmark or request secure access.

I have incoming/outgoing connections allowed, and also tried with secure access to the folder and then creating a bookmark to the socket, doesn't work. Is it simply not possible to select sockets in a sandboxed app?